# Specify openvpn/wireguard server outbound ip

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, iptables

I have a VPS with a interface `eth0`, that has 2 IPs, `10.0.0.3` (default) and `10.0.0.5`. The 2 IPs are mirrored to external IP by ISP, `1.0.0.10`, `2.0.0.20`. (Google and Oracle Cloud have the similar mechanism as I know).

I only know how to NAT tun0 to the eth0 with only one IP.

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Now I want to NAT `tun0` to `eth0` (`10.0.0.5`), how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

`tun` interface **can not be bridged**, because it doesn't emulate any link layer protocol. `tap` interface emulates Ethernet, which can be bridged.

However, you only use `tap` and bridge when you are certain you need exactly it, because `tun` is better supported (it's the only supported on Android devices, for example) and it is more efficient, because it doesn't need to encapsulate link layer headers, leaving more room to the useful data.

`tun` will have its own address (whichever you set up in the VPN server config file). But if VPN packets are routed out via `eth0` they will be translated to some address you set on the `eth0`. Which one? Right now it is random; if you want to NAT your VPN users to address `10.0.0.5`, remove your `MASQUERADE` rule and add the following `SNAT` rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s <vpn-network> -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.5
```

`vpn-network` is something like `10.8.0.0/24` or whatever you set it to be in the server config.

---

Also, it seems you are confusing the *bridge* term with the *bind* term.

If you want OpenVPN to only receive (encrypted) packets on `10.0.0.5` and to send them back using `10.0.0.5`, you need to **bind** it to this address. Add to the server configuration file:

```
local 10.0.0.5
```

Or specify it on the command line: `--local 10.0.0.5`.